# Replace a whole word except inside square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

How can I Regex \b boundaries except [ ]

My test input is  -

```
" exec [exec]
[ exec]
exec
exec 
exec   
exec
       exec 
(exec
exec)
(exec)"
```

The Output that I want get, look like this -

```
" EXECUTE [exec]
[ exec]
EXECUTE
EXECUTE 
EXECUTE   
EXECUTE
       EXECUTE 
(EXECUTE
EXECUTE)
(EXECUTE)"
```

The Regex that I use is - `(?<!\[)(\s+)(\b)exec(\b)`
The Replace string is - `$1EXECUTE`

the output that I get is -

```
" EXECUTE [exec]
[ exec]
EXECUTE
EXECUTE 
EXECUTE   
EXECUTE
       EXECUTE 
(exec
EXECUTE)
(exec)"
```

Help please...

Thancks Sharon

Comment: What is the regex flavor/programming language?

Comment: C#, SQL Server clr

Comment: Can you run a `Regex.Replace` on this string?

Comment: Does `\b` match `(` and `)`? You could try to match them manually, like `(\b|[()])`

Comment: Use `\bexec\b(?!\s*\])` for search and `EXECUTE` for replacement

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The updated regex also works if there are spaces between the `[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `(?!<\[\s*)\bexec(?!\]\s*)`, it uses negative lookahead to check if there are no `[` or `]` brackets around  `exec`. Read this : http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: This will not replace [`exec` in a `exec]`](https://regex101.com/r/zG0zU2/1). This regex just does not check if the word *is inside* square brackets. Moreover, the `(?!<\[)\bexec(?!\])` regex is actually just wrong as `ex` is not `<[` and the initial lookahead will always be true.

Comment: OP did not want to replace `exec]`

Comment: If the OP figures this isn't what he/she needs the answer can always be un-accepted.

Comment: If you tested your regex, you would know where it goes wrong. At least read my first comment, and fix.

Comment: As I said, if the op figures this isn't what he/she wants he/she can accept another answer.

Comment: I tried to do an `if else` statement in the `regex` to match `[` and `]` separately, but I'm not that proficient with `regex`. If OP does indeed want that please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You may capture the strings inside brackets and restore them in the replacement with a match evaluator:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\[[^][]*])|\bexec\b",
       m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : "EXECUTE");
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/RS0w2i):

```
var input = " exec [exec]\n[ exec]\nexec\nexec \nexec   \nexec\n       exec \n(exec\nexec)\n(exec)"; 
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\[[^][]*])|\bexec\b",
            m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : "EXECUTE");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The `(\[[^][]*])|\bexec\b` regex will capture into Group 1 all `[...]` strings with `(\[[^][]*])`, and then will just match a whole word `exec`. Once there is a match, we check if Group 1 matched with `m.Groups[1].Success`. If yes, just insert it back, if not, replace with `EXECUTE`.